# Communication between Raspberry Pi 3 and Samsung Gear S2

Tags: android, android-studio, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, iot

I would like to make a communication between a Raspeberry Pi 3 and Samsung Gear s2.

My Basic idea is to replace my Android Phone with a raspberry board. And make a Coupling between the two. Then i would like to make an App on the Rasperry Pi which will send a Notication Msg to the Gear S2.

Based my research the Gear S2 can be connected only a certain android phones.
Im confused hweather this could be done or not?

Should i use a android OS or a Tizen OS on RP3 .Can i develop an app for RP3 using the Androind Studio or Tizen Studio?If anyone has seen a similar project pls update me

Comment: I found a discussion here [link](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/raspberry-pi-3-communicating-with-gear-s2/201/297699?boardName=SDK&startId=zzzzz). It suggests to work with Bluetooth API and SPP.

Comment: Thats me who open the discussion :). Thanks Yasin

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should have a look at Samsung ARTIK Cloud.
I connected my Raspberry pi3 via ARTIK Cloud to my GearS2 and can now switch on/off my TV using sone 433mhz remote plugs